# UItableview help please? It won't display a background, textbox or submit button - iPhone SDK / Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Having trouble implementing the following to look like this:

Design view: http://i53.tinypic.com/2hqe9lk.png

Simulator view: http://i56.tinypic.com/2luw68j.png

It doesn't display the background, textbox, nor the submit button :( All it displays is the table.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Code for the view is as follows;

**BooksTableViewController.m**

```
//
//  BooksTableViewController.m
//  ORBooks
//
//  Created by Elisabeth Robson on 6/19/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Elisabeth Robson. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BooksTableViewController.h"
#import "BookDetailViewController.h"
#import "ORBooksAppDelegate.h"

@implementation BooksTableViewController
@synthesize booksArray;
@synthesize bookDetailViewController;
@synthesize number;

/*
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {
 // Override initWithStyle: if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
 if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
 }
 return self;
 }
 */

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target: nil action: nil];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem: newBackButton];    
    [newBackButton release];

    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sub1", @"sub2", nil];
    self.booksArray = array;
    [array release]; 

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


/*
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 }
 */
/*
 - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidAppear:animated];     
 }

/*
 - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
 }
 */
/*
 - (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
 [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
 // Return YES for supported orientations
 return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }
 */

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;//[self.booksArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.text = [booksArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    // AnotherViewController *anotherViewController = [[AnotherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherView" bundle:nil];
    // [self.navigationController pushViewController:anotherViewController];
    // [anotherViewController release];

    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    if (self.bookDetailViewController == nil) {
        BookDetailViewController *aBookDetail = [[BookDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BookDetailView" bundle:nil];
        self.bookDetailViewController = aBookDetail;
        [aBookDetail release];
    }
    //bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [booksArray objectAtIndex:row]];

    //ORBooksAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //[delegate.booksNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];
}


/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
 }   
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }   
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
 }
 */


/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */


- (void)dealloc {
    [bookDetailViewController release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

**BooksTableViewController.h**

```
//
//  BooksTableViewController.h
//  ORBooks
//
//  Created by Elisabeth Robson on 6/19/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Elisabeth Robson. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BookDetailViewController;

// don't need to specify the delegate, datasource interfaces; UITableViewController gets those automatically
@interface BooksTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextField *number;
    IBOutlet UITableView *booksTableView;
    NSMutableArray *booksArray;
    BookDetailViewController *bookDetailViewController;
}

- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *booksArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BookDetailViewController *bookDetailViewController;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the UITableViewController to UIViewController in the header file.
What you are doing is adding everything to the tableview. Instead you'll have to add your tableview to the UIViewController and the same for UITextfield and UIButton.

Rest is fine.

Comment: Thanks- I've tried that previously and all I get now is: http://i55.tinypic.com/2eb633p.png